# Saving a matplotlib graph as an image field in database

Tags: python, django, matplotlib, imagefield

I just started learning `matplotlib` and I want to use it in one of my django apps. So I wanted to know how I can save the graph generated in an image field of my models, so that I can retrive whenever needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`matplotlib.pyplot.savefig`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig) accepts file-like object as the first parameter. You can pass `StringIO`/`BytesIO` (according to your python version).

```
f = StringIO()
plt.savefig(f)
```

Then, use [`django.core.files.ContentFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/#the-contentfile-class) to convert the string to [`django.core.files.File`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/#django.core.files.File) (because [`FieldFile.save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.save) accepts only accept an instance of `django.core.files.File`).

```
content_file = ContentFile(f.getvalue())
model_object = Model(....)
model_object.image_field.save('name_of_image', content_file)
model_object.save()
```

Comment: Am using python 2.7 and I get a `not defined` error for both StringIO and BytesIO

Comment: @AswinMurugesh, Import it. `from io import BytesIO` / `from StringIO import StringIO` / `from cStringIO import StringIO`.

Comment: @AswinMurugesh, http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html  /  http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO

Comment: what is `fig` actually? Is it a savefig object or a pyplot object?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh, an instance of [`matplotlib.pyplot`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#module-matplotlib.pyplot). I renamed `fig` to `plt` because `plt` is commonly used name.

Comment: plt.save(f) gives me this error: `module' object has no attribute 'save'`

Comment: @AswinMurugesh, It is `savefig`. I misspelled it in the code. Sorry.

Comment: The view works without errors. how do I check if it is saved correctly?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh, Please read [Managing files | Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/)

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8598881/1308967) it says: For Python2.6 or better, use `io.BytesIO` instead of `cStringIO.StringIO` for forward-compatibility. In Python3, the `cStringIO`, `StringIO` modules are gone. Their functionality is all in the `io` module.