# Writing figure to Google Cloud Storage instead of local drive

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to upload the figure which is made with matplotlib to GCS.

Current code:

```
from tensorflow.gfile import MakeDirs, Open
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

_LOGDIR = "{date:%Y%m%d-%H%M%S}".format(date=datetime.datetime.now())

_PATH_LOGDIR = 'gs://{0}/logs/{1}'.format('skin_cancer_mnist', _LOGDIR)
MakeDirs(_PATH_LOGDIR))


def saving_figure(path_logdir):
    data = np.arange(0, 21, 2)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
    plt.plot(data)
    fig.savefig("{0}/accuracy_loss_graph.png".format(path_logdir))
    plt.close()

saving_figure(_PATH_LOGDIR)
```

"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 512, in print_png
    filename_or_obj = open(filename_or_obj, 'wb')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs://skin_cancer_mnist/logs/20190116-195604/accuracy_loss_graph.png'

(The directory exists, I checked)

I could change the source code of matplotlib to use the Open method of tf.Gfile.Open, but there should be a better option...

Answer (score 4):

Joans 2nd Option didn't work for me, I found a solution that worked for me:

```
from google.cloud import storage
import io

def saving_figure(path_logdir):
    data = np.arange(0, 21, 2)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
    plt.plot(data)
    fig_to_upload = plt.gcf()

    # Save figure image to a bytes buffer
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    fig_to_upload.savefig(buf, format='png')

    # init GCS client and upload buffer contents
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket('skin_cancer_mnist')
    blob = bucket.blob('logs/20190116-195604/accuracy_loss_graph.png')  
    blob.upload_from_file(buf, content_type='image/png', rewind=True)
```

Comment: You don't use path_logdir inside the function. Is it 'logs/20190116-195604/accuracy_loss_graph.png'?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot directly upload a file to Google Cloud Storage using the python `open` function (which is the one that `matplotlib.pyplot.savefig` is using behind the curtains). 
Instead, you should use the [Cloud Storage Client Library for Python](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python). Check this [documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/index.html) for details on how this library is used. This will allow you to manipulate files and upload/download them to GCS, among other things.

You will have to import this library in order to use it, you can install it by running `pip install google-cloud-storage` and import it as `from google.cloud import storage`.

As well, since the `plt.figure` is an object, and not the actual `.png` image that you want to upload, you cannot directly upload it to Google Cloud Storage either.

However you can do either one of the following:

**Option 1**: Save the image locally, and then upload it to Google Cloud Storage:

Using your code:

```
from google.cloud import storage

def saving_figure(path_logdir):
    data = np.arange(0, 21, 2)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
    plt.plot(data)
    fig.savefig("your_local_path/accuracy_loss_graph.png".format(path_logdir))
    plt.close()


    # init GCS client and upload file
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket('skin_cancer_mnist')
    blob = bucket.blob('logs/20190116-195604/accuracy_loss_graph.png')  # This defines the path where the file will be stored in the bucket
    your_file_contents = blob.upload_from_filename(filename="your_local_path/accuracy_loss_graph.png")
```

**Option 2**: Save the image result from the figure to a variable, then upload it to GCS as a string (of bytes):

I have found the following StackOverflow answer that seems to save the figure image into a `.png` byte string, however I haven't tried it myself.

Again, based in your code:

```
from google.cloud import storage
import io
import urllib, base64

def saving_figure(path_logdir):
    data = np.arange(0, 21, 2)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
    plt.plot(data)
    fig_to_upload = plt.gcf()

    # Save figure image to a bytes buffer
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    fig_to_upload.savefig(buf, format='png')
    buf.seek(0)
    image_as_a_string = base64.b64encode(buf.read())

    # init GCS client and upload buffer contents
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket('skin_cancer_mnist')
    blob = bucket.blob('logs/20190116-195604/accuracy_loss_graph.png')  # This defines the path where the file will be stored in the bucket
    your_file_contents = blob.upload_from_string(image_as_a_string, content_type='image/png')
```

**Edit**: Both options assume that the environment you are running the script from, has the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) installed, and a Google Cloud authenticated account activated (if you haven't, you can check [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication) that explains how to do it).

Comment: I think the key point is saving a file in memory, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598673/how-to-save-a-pylab-figure-into-in-memory-file-which-can-be-read-into-pil-image