# Is there a way to get networkx graph details as a PIL image?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, networkx

As there is a way of getting array information as a PIL Image by `Image.fromarray()` from array data.

I was wondering if there is a way of getting nx data into an image.

I looked into the documentation for [PIL Image](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html) but I could not figure out what could be useful in this case. I wanted to do with `nx.draw()` but returns a NoneType.

Edit: To be specific, I am looking for a way without saving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nx.draw` to create a matplotlib figure to create an image from using Pillow. You can use `io.BytesIO` as an intermediate similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598673/how-to-save-a-pylab-figure-into-in-memory-file-which-can-be-read-into-pil-image/8598881):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import io
from PIL import Image

im_io = io.BytesIO()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
...
nx.draw(G, ax=ax, ...)
fig.savefig(im_io, format='png')
im = Image.open(im_io)
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without having to save the figure? Like we get directly from an array using `Image.fromarray()`.

Comment: Technically this doesn't create a file. What array would you be creating the image from?

Comment: I do not have an array. I have an nx graph that I would like to be formed into an image so that I can feed it to a CNN.