# save only an extent of the map using matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I am using matplotlib along with the basemap with the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap,cm

#Map Center
core = (151.35,-23.92)

LAT = core[1]
LON = core[0]
zoom_scale = 5/111
#create a bounding box from the central co=ordinates
bbox = [LAT-zoom_scale,LAT+zoom_scale, LON-zoom_scale,LON+zoom_scale]

#create an instance of the basemap object
m = Basemap(epsg=4326,llcrnrlat=bbox[0],urcrnrlat=bbox[1],\
                 llcrnrlon=bbox[2],urcrnrlon=bbox[3],resolution='i')

#Add and arcgis basemap
m.arcgisimage(service="World_Imagery", xpixels=7000, verbose=False)   
t = Bbox.from_extents(151.324,-23.9414,151.357,-23.9117)

#save the image
plt.savefig(plotOutDir+'/'+ "new", bbox_inches = t,pad_inches = 0)
```

This is the output
[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oice1.png)

However this is saving the whole map as an image.
Is there is a way to save just a small extent of this map as a png by passing in an extent object as one of the arguments in the plt.savefig method?
or is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Please, share more details about your code and what is / isn't happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, here's a somewhat roundabout idea to solve this problem. You can crop a PIL `Image` object, by specifying pixels to crop like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43591567/13095028. The cropped image can then be saved to disk with `Image.save()`. You can also convert a `matplotlib` `figure` to PIL `Image` like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61755066/13095028.

Combining these ideas gives the following which you can plug under your existing code. You'll need to convert your bbox from inches to pixels.

```py
# Import PIL
from PIL import Image

# Grab current figure object
fig = plt.gcf()

# Use code snippet from 2nd link to convert matplotlib fig to PIL Image
def fig2img(fig):
    """Convert a Matplotlib figure to a PIL Image and return it"""
    import io
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(buf)
    buf.seek(0)
    img = Image.open(buf)
    return img

img = fig2img(fig)

# Use code from 1st link to crop and save
# Note: Fill in your bbox area in pixels here!!
area = (400, 400, 800, 800)
cropped_img = img.crop(area)
cropped_img.save(plotOutDir+'/'+ "new")
```

Comment: my bounding box is a geographic extent