# How do I get a file like object in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have used `plt.plot(plot1['x'], plot1['y'])` to produce a plot from my "plot1" dataset.

I want to get a file like object from this plot how can I get it done?

Here is the full code:

[image]

Comment: (a) Don't post code as images! (b) What should be in the filelike object? An image, maybe? In what format?

Comment: `plt.savefig()`?

Comment: I want to attach the plot into an discord.Embed so I need a file like object

Comment: plt.savefig() would save it locally I want to avoid that

Comment: So use `plt.savefig()` and write it to a BytesIO object...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598673/how-to-save-a-pylab-figure-into-in-memory-file-which-can-be-read-into-pil-image

Comment: BytesIO is like FileIO but with bytes instead of text. Images like png use bytes. The enables you to save your file "in memory" rather than on the disc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it looks like you want to save your plot as a format that can be copied in instant messaging:

```
import io, base64
picture = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(picture, format='png')
picture.seek(0)
picture_b64 = base64.b64encode(picture.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution,

```py
import io

buf = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buf, format='png')
buf.seek(0)
file = discord.File(buf, "image.png")
buf.close()
return file #  or do anything with the file
```